# Facebook: Create tab with custom Page Tab URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a method to create a new tab for an app and directly add the Page Tab URL.

After a long search on the internet, it looks impossible. But it isn't, because there are some sites who make use of this method. But I'm not really sure of they directly add the Page Tab URL or first create a simple tab and update the tab with a post request and change the Page Tab URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a page tab is nothing else then an iframe, you can do whatever you want in that iframe...

for changing the page_tab_url via api see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: That is correct, but I would like to change the Page Tab URL of the tab (iframe) with the Facebook API (without developers.facebook.com etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is it! I was looking for a long time for this! Thnks!